# parcel build failed adn couldn't get my entry

Tags: javascript, parcel

on trying run start / npm start on parcel index.html

```
server running at http://localhost:1234
```

```
 Build failed.
```

```
unknown: Entry C:\Users\hazem\OneDrive\Desktop\complete-javascript-course-master\18-forkify\index.html does not exist
```

what is wrong here

I want to install sass files but parcel couldn't reach to my files

Comment: `complete-javascript-course-master\18-forkify\index.html` does not exist?